# LAG() Function To Get The Average REDSHIFT

Tags: amazon-redshift, average, lag

I am trying to find the AVERAGE time users spend whilst going through registration within an app.

**This is my dataset:**

| customer_id | app_event | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | OPEN_APP | '2022-01-01 19:00:25' |
| 1 | CLICK_REGISTER | '2022-01-01 19:00:30' |
| 1 | ENTER_DETAILS | '2022-01-01 19:00:40' |
| 1 | CLOSE_APP | '2022-01-01 19:00:50' |
| 2 | OPEN_APP | '2022-01-01 20:00:25' |
| 2 | CLICK_REGISTER | '2022-01-01 20:00:26' |
| 2 | ENTER_DETAILS | '2022-01-01 20:00:27' |
| 2 | CLOSE_APP | '2022-01-01 20:00:28' |

**This is my query:**

```
WITH cte AS (
SELECT
    customer_id,  
    app_event, 
    timestamp AS ts, 
    EXTRACT(EPOCH ((ts - lag(ts, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id, app_event ORDER BY ts ASC))) AS time_spent
FROM table
GROUP BY customer_id, app_event, timestamp
)
SELECT 
    app_event, 
    AVG(time_spent) 
FROM cte 
GROUP BY app_event
```

**This is the outcome I want:**

| app_event | time_spent |
| --- | --- |
| OPEN_APP |  |
| CLICK_REGISTER | 3 |
| ENTER_DETAILS | 5.5 |
| CLOSE_APP | 5.5 |

Answer (score 0):

I see a few issues with your query.  You haven't posted your exact concern so I'll operate from these.

First EXTRACT() operates on a timestamp but the difference between two timestamps is an interval.  I think you want to use DATEDIFF(sec, ts1, ts2) which will give the time difference (in seconds) between the two timestamps.

Most importantly you are partitioning by app_event which will make LAG() only consider events with the same value.  So you will get the difference between the timestamps for only for CLICK_REGISTER for example.  You need to remove app_event from the partition list of the LAG() function.